# How to add a sitewide text area to a Wordpress Site that can be changed in the dashboard

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm asking this here as I'm not even sure what to Google with a question like this.

On a site for a recent client they have a tagline that will be changed monthly. I currently have a separate tagline.php file with a simple:

```
// Edit the Main Tagline Here
$tagline = 'Defeat the Fear of Change Today';
// End Main Tagline Section
```

This file is included in the header.php file and the variable $tagline is called in the appropriate place.

I put the tagline in a separate file so when the client's web guys edit the file they can't really screw up anything other than the tagline, however I have been asked to make the tagline a custom field that is set in the WordPress dashboard without the end user having to edit any php files.

I'm not sure what to google for to find out how to do this as it's a complex question. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Wordpress Customizer API. Add a new section "Tagline", add setting and then add control.

I personally find this **[tutorial](http://themefoundation.com/wordpress-theme-customizer/)** very useful.

Once you've added the required code, you just have to call it in the file, you have a functional for that too in the customizer API.

Comment: This works. The other answers seemed geared toward individual pages or posts, not a site-wide tagline.

Answer (score 1):

you just to add custom field to any post which specifically for tagline
all you need to do is create custom field e.g. name tagline and value as required.

then in header.php where you want to display this use following code:

```
<?php $tag =  get_post_custom_values('tagline');
  echo $tag[0];
?>
```

$post_id : your post for showing tagline

this will show your tagline